# How to Check If 10 Most Recent Entries in MySQL DB Begin with a String Using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to allow people to write something like BOLD: or ITALIC: at the beginning of their message to make bold or italic. The only way I can think of is to get the total amount of entries by ID and minus 10 then make an IF statement and minus 9 and so on. Is there a single statement I could query to check if the string in the database begins a certain way and display it in HTML in bold or italic if it does?

```
<?PHP

$A = "localhost"; // Server Name
$B = "root";      // MySQL Username
$C = "";          // MySQL Password
$D = "sql";       // Database

$CONNECT = new mysqli($A, $B, $C, $D);

if ($CONNECT->connect_error) {
    die('<DIV>Connection Failed</DIV>');
}

echo "<DIV>Connected</DIV>";

if (isset($_POST['MSG'])) {
    $MSG = htmlspecialchars($_POST['MSG']);
    $SQL = "INSERT INTO Messages (Message) VALUES ('$MSG')";

    if ($CONNECT->query($SQL) === TRUE) {
        echo "<DIV>Message Sent</DIV>";
    } else {
        echo "<DIV>Error Sending Message</DIV>";
    }
}

$SELECT = 'SELECT * FROM Messages ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 10';
$RESULT = $CONNECT->query($SELECT);

if (mysqli_num_rows($RESULT) > 0) {
    while ($ROW = mysqli_fetch_assoc($RESULT)) {
        echo '<DIV>ID: ' . $ROW['ID'] . ' MSG: ' . $ROW['Message'] . '</DIV>';
    }
}
```

I added in some code if somebody begins their message with "'", but the type of strpos if statement doesn't work in the while loop for retrieving messages.

```
if (isset($_POST['MSG'])) {
$MSG = htmlspecialchars($_POST['MSG']);
$SQL = "INSERT INTO Messages (Message) VALUES ('$MSG')";

if ($CONNECT->query($SQL) === TRUE) {
    echo "<DIV>Message Sent</DIV>";
} else {
    if (substr($MSG,0,1 == '\'')) {
        echo "<DIV>Error Sending Message</DIV>";
    } else {
        echo "<DIV>Nice Try :')</DIV>";
    }
}
```

Comment: since you want to display all messages anyway, whether they begin with a special keyword or not, altering the SQL would not help in my opinion. you should check for those keywords in the while loop.

Comment: So I could do an if statement then an else statement which echoes the message as normal if it does not begin with BOLD: for example?

Comment: Why not use another column in your database that indicates whether a message is bold or italic?

Comment: Hmm, that's a good idea. I will try that.

Comment: exactly. but whether you take EatPeanutButters advice or not, you would still need an if-elseif-else statement in the while loop. I myself would not add another table-column and just look if the string starts with 'BOLD:'. for this check i would use [strpos](http://php.net/manual/de/function.strpos.php)

Comment: I tried the if-elseif-else statement to see if the $MSG started with BOLD: and it did not work. Could you provide me with the syntax, Cashbee, please?

Comment: if(strpos($ROW['message'], 'BOLD:') !== false){..}

Comment: Kind of works but prints the message twice now.

Comment: im preparing a full answer with the whole code, give me 2-3 minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for this question to have an answer i will sum up what i did in the comments:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($RESULT) > 0) {
    while ($ROW = mysqli_fetch_assoc($RESULT)) {
        $message = $ROW['message'];
        if(strpos($ROW['message'], 'BOLD:') !== false){
            $message = '<strong>'.substr($ROW['message'], 5).'</strong>';
        } else if(strpos($ROW['message'], 'ITALIC:') !== false){
            $message = '<i>'.substr($ROW['message'], 7).'</i>';
        }
        echo '<DIV>ID: ' . $ROW['ID'] . ' MSG: ' . $message . '</DIV>';
    }
}
```

edit: oops i forgot to add the different style tags..
for bold you can wrap the $message in a strong -tag. for italic its the i -tag

edit2: included tags in the code

Comment: What and how would I include the bold and italic tags?

Comment: Like this? $Message = '<B>' . substr($ROW['Message'], 5) . '</B>';

Comment: edited again, added the tags in the code. <B> is not a valid tag. its <strong>

Comment: Thank you, both B and STRONG works though. This helped me a lot!

Comment: oh didnt know that b still works. Sure, glad to help.